# Implementation of Greedy algorithm

Tags: c++, greedy

I'm trying to implement my own version of Greedy algorithm for the knapsack problem(the one in which you are allowed to add fractions of an object not neccesarly objects as wholes).

I have written the below code following this logic:
- created an array named 'profitPerWeight' in which I stored the values of profit/weight for all the objects
- in a 'knapSack()' function I check which item has the most profitable value, and check with another function called 'getFraction()' what fraction of the object fits in the bag(the bag capacity is 15 in my case).
- in the 'getFraction()' function I return 1 if the item fits as a whole or which fraction of it fits(e.g: if bag weight is currently is 7 and item is 2 I return 1 because the item can fit in the bag without going over capacity: 15. If say weight is 7 and item is 9 I return 9%7 because only a part(2) of the item(9) could go in the bag without going over the allowed capacity.
- then I add the fraction of the item in the bag and I have another array 'bagContent[]' which stores for each object the fraction of it that was included in the bag.

E.g: if bagContent would be = {1,1,0,0,2/3} means I stored in the bag: obj0, obj1, and 2/3*obj4.

The output of this problem is supposed to be:
1*first 2/3*second 1*third 0*fourth 1*fifth 1*sixth 1*seventh

However I get a different one when I run my solution:
1*first 1*second 1*third 0*fourth 1*fifth 1*sixth 1*seventh.

As you can see the second one is '1' instead of '2/3' :(. And I have no ideea why I'm guessing it's something with decimals that I need to fix. I tried few things but they did not work. Or perhaps there is something wrong with my logic. I'm not very experienced with algorithms :( .Please tell me what am I doing wrong and how can I correct this. Thank you. The code is below:

```
// Knapsack problem: Greedy method

// Objects: 1,  2,   3,   4,  5,  6,  7
// Profits: 10, 5,   15,  7,  6,  18, 3
// Weights: 2,  3,   5,   7,  1,  4,  1

// Fill a 15kg knapsack with the objects(they can be divisible) so that the profit is maximum

// Output should be:
// 1*first 2/3*second 1*third 0*fourth 1*fifth 1*sixth 1*seventh

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

char *objects[] = {"First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth", "Fifth", "Sixth", "Seventh"};
int profits[] = {10, 5, 15, 7, 6, 18, 3};
int weights[] = {2, 3, 5, 7, 1, 4, 1};
double profitPerWeight[7] = {5, 1.3, 3, 1, 6, 4.5, 3};
int bagWeight = 0;
int bagCapacity = 15;
int fraction;
int bagContent[7] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
int itemToAddIndex = 0;

// function that returns the index of most profitable item in 'profitPerWeight[]'
int MaxProfitItem()
{
 int index = 0;
 int mostPr = profitPerWeight[0];
 for(int i=1; i<7; i++)
 {
  if(profitPerWeight[i] > mostPr)
  {
   mostPr = profitPerWeight[i];
   index = i;
  }
 }
 return index;
}

// function that returns true if the current fraction of an
// item can fit in the bag or false if the
// current fraction of an item cannot fit in the bag
bool itemFits(int index)
{
 if(bagWeight + weights[index] <= 15)
  return true;

 return false;
}

// function that divides an item with a specified fraction
void divideItem(int index, double fraction)
{
 weights[index] = weights[index] / fraction;
}

// function that returns which fraction of an item can fit in the bag
double getFraction(int index)
{
 double fraction;  // the fraction is initially 1
 if(itemFits(index))
 {
  fraction = 1;
 }

 else
 {
  fraction = weights[index] % bagCapacity;
 }

 return fraction;


}

// puts fraction of item in bag and updates capacity&weight of bag
void putInBag(int itemToAddIndex, double fraction)
{
 profitPerWeight[itemToAddIndex] = 0; // disegard this so it won't be seen as max next time we look for most valuable item
 bagCapacity = bagCapacity - fraction * weights[itemToAddIndex];
 bagWeight = bagWeight + fraction * weights[itemToAddIndex];
 bagContent[itemToAddIndex] = fraction;
}

// function that solves the problem using greedy approach
void knapSack()
{
  while(bagWeight<=15)
  {
   itemToAddIndex = MaxProfitItem();       // select the most profit/weight valuable item
   fraction = getFraction(itemToAddIndex); // see which fraction of it fits in the bag
   putInBag(itemToAddIndex, fraction);     // put the fraction of item which fits in bag
  }

  for(int i=0; i<7; i++)
  {
   cout << *(objects+i) << "*" << bagContent[i] << " ";
  }
}

int main()
{
 knapSack();

}
```

Comment: You didn't ask a question. And correct me if I'm wrong, with allowance of fraction items, why would you not just fill the bag with the item with highest price/weight ratio?

Comment: @PasserBy because I need to see what fraction of an item I can add to the bag so it doesn't go over it's capacity. For example if an object is 2kg and my capacity is(14/15) I can't add the full object as that would go over max allowed capacity so I need to add just a fraction of it(1 in this case)

Answer (score 0):

Your function `double getFraction(int index)` has some flaws. It shouldn't be comparing the weight of the item to the bagCapacity (the MAX), it should be comparing the weight to the current remaining capacity.. ie the bagCapacity - bagWeight.  But also, I'm not sure why you are doing a % (modulus), when you should be dividing to get the fraction.  ALSO, you're dividing two ints into a double, and you need to do a cast for that.  Try changing the function to the following:

```
double getFraction(int index)
{
 double fraction;  // the fraction is initially 1
 if(itemFits(index))
 {
  fraction = 1;
 }

 else
 {
  fraction = (double)(bagCapacity - bagWeight) / (double)weights[index]; 
 }

 return fraction;


}
```

Edit: And also, your array only holds ints, when you want fractions (or actually decimal points).  Change `int bagContent[7] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0};` to `double bagContent[7] = {0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0};`